# ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY generator-karma@>=0.9.0

Tags: npm, sass, karma-runner, npm-install

So basically I want to understand why when I run `npm install sass-loader node-sass --save-dev` I get this error

> ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY generator-karma@>=0.9.0

However it's clear that Karma is installed since when I run `npm install generator-karma` I see that :

```
└─┬ generator-karma@2.0.0    <--- Which mean karma is there...
  └─┬ yeoman-generator@0.22.6
    ├── async@1.5.2
...
```

I've read answer explaining I should use `npm install -g grunt-cli bower yo generator-karma generator-angular` but this is not helping much.

Should I uninstall and reinstall a clean `node_modules` ?

Comment: It never hurts to run `rm -rf node_modules` and then `npm i` to reinstall everything listed in package.json. It's the equivalent of "turning it off and on again".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

npm no longer installs module dependencies automatically. That means you have to install the dependencies modules yourself. Basically if you run `npm install generator-karma@>=0.9.0` and then run the your previous `npm install` command you should be good to go.